# how to insert null values in database through text boxes in c#.net

Tags: .net

how to fill null value into database through text boxes when I don't want to insert the value into that text boxes.
if I insert with out fill the text boxes it shows the following error"incorrect syntax near ','"
I am using Sql server2008r2

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show your approach so that we can help to fix it.

Comment: Add you code, as I'm not aware any people on this site can mind-read (except maybe Jon Skeet).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you use sql management studio.Combination ctrl + 0 will help you

Comment: I didn't know that Ctrl+0 helps to fix all of my errors.